# How to run createsuperuser from PyDev Django shell

Tags: python, django

I can't figure out how to do `python manage.py createsuperuser` in my PyDev Django shell.

I was hoping something below would work, but nothing did. I've never really used these shells before, and hope there's a way to create this superuser with a shell.

```
import manage
python manage.py createsuperuser
  File "<ipython-input-15-fcfe38f02d6e>", line 1
    python manage.py createsuperuser
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried doing it with the Windows cmd, which led to this error:

```
C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src>python manage.py createsuperuser
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 25, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
ImportError: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Rasmus\workspace\Crowd\src\Cr\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    class User(models.Model):
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 307, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 662, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 28, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'
```

Which I find weird seeing as my Django is connected to my database and that I can store and retrieve objects from the database within PyDev.

Are there other ways to `createsuperuser` than using shell or cmd? Like doing it with a method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "myapp.settings")
from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
execute_from_command_line(["manage.py","createsuperuser"])
```

Comment: Running this in shell gives me a list of commands. Can you explain  how to conduct this?

Comment: this is the code that runs when you run `python manage.py createsuperuser` from the commandline

Comment: @vandelay whoops i guess it expects manage.py as its first argument in argv

Comment: Gives me a Superuser creation skipped due to not running in a TTY. Guess I have to try and get my cmd to work.

Comment: i think you can pass in all the required arguments as keyword arguments

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error information "loading MySQLdb module: No module named 'MySQLdb'", you need to install [MySQL-python](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/1.2.5)

Comment: Well it's already installed since I can do mysql operations through django?

Comment: @vandelay set up the PYTHONPATH by referring the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7. Add the path to MySQLdb to PYTHONPATH